# QGIS: global solar irradiance calculation and analysis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator, saga

I am working on a climate change project where I want to have a map showing the average temperature per month at a local scale. I want to use the following data: average temperature from weather stations, DEM and global solar irradiance. I have the weather stations data and the DEM. I made a map taking into account the average temperature and elevation using SAGA kriging and the raster calculator in QGIS. Now I want to add solar irradiance but I don't know how to calculate it and how to consider it in my analysis. I know that what I want to do is possible with the area solar radiation tool of ArcGIS but I want to do this in QGIS exclusively. Is this even possible or should I code in R knowing that I have no experience with R?

I tried different tools from GRASS like r.sun.incidout etc. but I don't have any result. Can someone please explain which method I should follow because I might going in the wrong direction.

Comment: The tool needed for this application is _Potential Incoming Solar Radiation_ in SAGA GIS. It is able to calculate total insolation. I now need a way to implement the total insolation in my analysis. How do I calculate the average temperature considering the total insolation?

Comment: This has been studied to determine growing conditions for plants, especially crops. One resource that has a lot of formulas related to the topic is _Modelling Potential Crop Growth Processes: Textbook with Exercises_ by J. Goudriaan and H.H. van Laar. I don't know for sure that what you need is in there, but I used that text to find formulas related to how temperature changes with latitude and day of year, so I bet they've covered your topic.

Comment: You can compute it daily with this addon, then easily aggregate in GRASS GIS with the t.* temporal modules: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/addons/r.sun.daily.html

Comment: Would not be better to download some irradiation data from existing databases for your locations? E.g. Global Solar Atlas (in case you need only long-term averages) or ERA5 climate reanalysis (in case the time-series is needed) or SARAH, NSRDB (depends on the region).